# show empty data points on anychart line graph with dateTime axis

Tags: anychart

I have a simple dataset with time series data points that i would like to plot on a per-second accuracy. But the data is ticker data so not every point is represented, only on price change.

Here is a simple example where the price goes `14:08, 14:09, 14:10 ... 14:15`

https://playground.anychart.com/ZIT0QuAF/1

Is it possible to display the gap/time passed between data points, either with blank space or probably better the x-axis for each second and just an extended line ( maybe dotted or different colour ) connecting the points.

Thank you.

Comment: There are many things you can achieve with some extra code. Do you want to show only points with blanks between them? Or connect them with dotted line? Like this - https://playground.anychart.com/eSe47R5T The gap time you can show in the tooltip, for example.

Comment: thanks. The datetime x-axis should always have a per-second resolution. For example, there is a data point for `14:30:10` and `14:30:15` but no ticker data was received for `14:30:11, 14:30:12, 14:30:13, 14:30:14` so the `10` and `15` points are directly connected. To better illustrate that there was some time passed in between these points it would be nice if anychart could be told that for the datetime x-axis that data should be there for each second.. if missing then draw the gap with either blank space or better use the dotted line to connect the available points. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see your requirements. You can achieve that very easy. As a default and as in the sample you provided, you use the ordinal based scale. To better illustrate that there was some time passed in between ticker points you should use scatter based scale. Just use the following line in your code:

```
chart.xScale('scatter');
```

Now all points follow strictly the time coordinate and all gaps between are showed. Also, all points are connected with dotted line. Please, check a sample below

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  // create data table on loaded data
  var table = anychart.data.table("epoch");

  table.addData([
  {
    last: 0.00000462,
    epoch: 1520260206263,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0,
    volDiff: 0,
    percentFromStart: 0.00000000
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000558,
    epoch: 1520260207391,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -17.20430108,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 20.77922078
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000585,
    epoch: 1520260208131,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -4.61538462,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 26.62337662
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000680,
    epoch: 1520260209293,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -13.97058824,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 47.18614719
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000693,
    epoch: 1520260210752,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -1.87590188,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 50.00000000
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000657,
    epoch: 1520260215326,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 5.47945205,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 42.20779221
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000700,
    epoch: 1520260225028,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -6.14285714,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 51.51515152
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000657,
    epoch: 1520260239317,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 6.54490107,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 42.20779221
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000624,
    epoch: 1520260240762,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 5.28846154,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 35.06493506
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000723,
    epoch: 1520260244015,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -13.69294606,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 56.49350649
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000740,
    epoch: 1520260245557,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -2.29729730,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 60.17316017
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000740,
    epoch: 1520260247146,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 60.17316017
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000740,
    epoch: 1520260258519,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 60.17316017
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000740,
    epoch: 1520260261733,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 60.17316017
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000713,
    epoch: 1520260262192,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 3.78681627,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 54.32900433
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000700,
    epoch: 1520260263087,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 1.85714286,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 51.51515152
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000657,
    epoch: 1520260264653,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 6.54490107,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 42.20779221
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000614,
    epoch: 1520260288009,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 7.00325733,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 32.90043290
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000614,
    epoch: 1520260295191,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 32.90043290
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000740,
    epoch: 1520260296127,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -17.02702703,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 60.17316017
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260299736,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -1.20160214,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260302084,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000562,
    epoch: 1520260304974,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 33.27402135,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 21.64502165
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000375,
    epoch: 1520260323816,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 49.86666667,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: -18.83116883
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260327149,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: -49.93324433,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260328543,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260335547,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000749,
    epoch: 1520260338101,
    vol: 0,
    volBase: 0,
    prcnt: 0.00000000,
    volDiff: NaN,
    percentFromStart: 62.12121212
  }
]);

  chart = anychart.stock();
  chart.xScale('scatter');

    var mappingLastPrice = table.mapAs({
    'value': "last"
  });
  
  var series1 = chart.plot(0).line(mappingLastPrice);
  series1.stroke('red','1', '2 10');
  series1.markers(true);
  series1.markers().fill('blue');
  series1.name("Last Price");

  chart.container('container').draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-stock.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This answer isn't working for me. I use anychart with angular 9, and when I adds line chart.xScale('scatter'); it gives me error Description: Chart scale should be only ordinal, linear, log, date-time type.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the Stock chart type? The Stock chart in Angular works well with scatter scale. Here is the code that works - https://gist.github.com/Shestac92/e33acd9c16f0f3bd1d54ff9fc7d70076

Comment: Already solved problem. This line of code    chart.xScale('date-time'); did what I want